# Exception: prefix (tns) not resolved

Tags: python, magento, odoo

I am facing this issue when I try to connect to magento SOAP AP:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/__init__.py", line 56, in qualify
    raise Exception('prefix (%s) not resolved' % p)
Exception: prefix (tns) not resolved
```

Can anyone help me with this? I saw that in the `wsdl.xml` the following is added:

```
<xsd:complexType name="AddressesAndPackages">
 <xsd:all>
  <xsd:element name="Addresses" type="tns:ArrayOfAddressData"/>
  <xsd:element name="Packages" type="tns:ArrayOfLineData"/>
 </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
```

the same code is working for other magento URL.

Comment: were you able to resolve this?